# Spring batch : AsyncItemProcessor does not terminate

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application packaged as a jar file.

I could execute the jar as mentioned below in the windows cmd prompt

> java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Ddivision=25 -Ddate= -Denv=dv -Dconn=45 -jar demo-jobs*.jar job-definition.xml jobName -next

Below is my bean definition

```
<batch:step id="baseStep" abstract="true">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk
                reader="cvsFileItemReader"
                processor="itemProcessorAsync"
                writer="itemWriterAsync"
                commit-interval="100" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.csv.Processor" />

<bean id="itemWriter" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.csv.Writer" >
    <!-- -->
        <constructor-arg ref = "hibernateItemWriter"/>
    <!-- -->
</bean>

<bean id="itemProcessorAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor">
    <property name="delegate" ref="itemProcessor"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutorAsync" />
</bean>

<bean id="itemWriterAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter">
    <property name="delegate" ref="itemWriter"/>
</bean>

<task:executor id="taskExecutorAsync" pool-size="5-25" queue-capacity="100"/>

<!-- Listener -->
<bean id="interceptingJobExecution" class="com.demo.batch.listener.JobListener" >
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutorAsync" /> -->
</bean>
```

Below is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("starting Main method" + new Date());

    String[] springConfig  = 
        {
                "spring/batch/jobs/job-definition.xml"
        };

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
    
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("starterJob");

    try {

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        logger.info("Exit Status : ", execution.getStatus());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = end - start;

    logger.info("Completed Main method : " + new Date());
    logger.info("Overall Execution time : " + elapsedTime);

}
```

it does not get terminated without "**System.exit(0);**"

however without **Async** it gets terminated, how do I make the application terminate without using "**System.exit(0);**"

**update:**: as suggested by Mahmoud Ben Hassine, tried the below**"

```
@Component
public class JobListener implements JobExecutionListener{
    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        //
        // Can Log || do some business code
        //
        System.out.println("## Intercepting Job Excution - Before Job!");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        System.out.println("## Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!");

        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            System.out.println("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");
        }

        taskExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Now it is getting terminated - however is this a right way?

```
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.006) [[]main] AbstractStep: Step: [stepcsv] executed in 33s426ms 
!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results
## Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!
!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.012) [[]main] ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: Shutting down ExecutorService 
# Base Job Listener - Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.021) [[]main] SimpleJobLauncher: Job: [FlowJob: [name=starterJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 33s506ms 
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.030) [[]main] App: Exit Status :  
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.030) [[]main] App: Completed Main method : Fri Oct 01 17:23:21 IST 2021 
INFO  : 10.01.2021:1723 (21.030) [[]main] App: Overall Execution time : 50362 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You have to define a component which extends **JobExecutionListenerSupport**  and this listener class would be responsible to terminate the process after completion of job. For more detail URL : https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: updated the question, please suggest.

Comment: What is the type of `taskExecutorAsync` that you set on the `itemProcessorAsync`? If this is a `TaskExecutor` that could be shutdown, you can inject it in the `JobListener` and call `shutdown` in `afterJob`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine -- have updated the question, please suggest.

Comment: Your updates look good to me, you now shutdown the taskexecutor in the the job listener and your app terminates correctly without `System.exit`. That answers your initial question.